# With this function I am suppose to ask for user input to see if they took a taxi, and I am getting this error, LNK1561 entry point must be defined

Tags: c++

I am working on this function that is suppose to ask for user input to see if they took a taxi or not and to calculate if they went over their allowed amount. When I go to compile it, I keep on getting this error LNK1561 entry point must be defined on line 1.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void   taxi(int, double&, double&)
{
    const double MAX_DAILY_TAXI_FEE = 40.00;
    int days;
    double spent;
    double  owed, budget;
    bool bFail;

    do
    {
        cout << "How many days did you spend using a taxi." << endl;
        cin >> days;
        bFail = cin.fail();

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        cout << "what was your total cost for the taxi in those days." << endl;
        cin >> spent;
        bFail = cin.fail();

        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

        budget = MAX_DAILY_TAXI_FEE * days; // calculate how the taxi fare budget
        owed = spent - budget;


        if ((spent < 0) && (days)) {
            cout << "You entered inputs were invalid please re-enter." << endl;
        }


    } while ((days < 0) && (spent < 0) && (bFail == true));


    if (owed <= 0)
    {
        cout << " You did not exceed your taxi allowance therefore you will not be charged any additional charges." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "You exceeded the taxi allowance therefore you are required to pay" << owed << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your `main`() function?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make an application?  If so, you need a main function.
If you're using visual studio and make a new project, you should get a function that looks like the following included when you create your project with the basic C console program template:

```
void main (int argc, char ** argv) {
}
```

(`char **` would be `_TCHAR` instead if you have your IDE set to use unicode.)

the main function is your program's "entry point"...the place where the computer goes to start running your program.  Without it, the computer has no idea where to start. It doesn't know to call your taxi function.

Comment: this is a sub function that is meant to be called by the main function.

Comment: oh i see is there a way to test my function without the main, i just want to see if the error checking and the cin fail and cin clear works etc.

Comment: Somewhere, you'll have to have a main function or a function called by a main function call your function.  The main function could be in a separate project and call your function if you make your function a static library, but this is much more complicated.